# how to sort array according to index of key in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

This is my array:

`$arr = array("pic0", "pic1", "pic2", "pic3", "pic4");`

how can I get the following strings:

```
$str1 = "pic1,pic2,pic3,pic4,pic0";
$str2 = "pic0,pic2,pic3,pic4,pic1";
$str3 = "pic0,pic1,pic3,pic4,pic2";
$str4 = "pic0,pic1,pic2,pic4,pic3";
$str5 = "pic0,pic1,pic2,pic3,pic4";
```

Comment: How are the strings to be created? It is not a list of all permutations or any real sorting ...

Comment: Is there any reason for the sorting to be like that?

Comment: I don't see any logic there, it looks like they are just randomly placed in the string... Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you want to just output random combinations of the items?

Comment: Hello guys, it's not just a random strings, if you look attentively, they have some sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use an array, not five strings:

```
$arr = array ("pic0", "pic1", "pic2", "pic3", "pic4");
$final = array ();

for($i=1, $c = count($arr); $i <= $c; ++$i) // loop n times
{
    $tmp = $arr; // tmp array
    $x = $arr[$i-1]; // get element to put in the end
    unset($tmp[$i-1]); // unset from the tmp array
    $final[$i] = implode(",", $tmp) . "," . $x; // concatenate the array with $x in the end
}

print_r($final);

/*
Array
(
    [1] => pic1,pic2,pic3,pic4,pic0
    [2] => pic0,pic2,pic3,pic4,pic1
    [3] => pic0,pic1,pic3,pic4,pic2
    [4] => pic0,pic1,pic2,pic4,pic3
    [5] => pic0,pic1,pic2,pic3,pic4
)
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code takes an array and sorts it given an index.
And returns a comma separated string with the array items.
For instance this code will take the 1st element [0] "pic0" and put it at the end of the string.

returning a string of "pic1,pic2,pic3,pic4,pic0"

```
$arr = array("pic0", "pic1", "pic2", "pic3", "pic4");

echo sort_by_index_to_string(0, $arr);

function sort_by_index_to_string($num, $arr)
{
  $v = $arr[$num];
  unset($arr[$num]);
  $arr[$num] = $v;

  return implode(",", $arr);
}
```